# Give body class if certain combination of elements exists in the DOM

Tags: jquery

I want to give the body a class when a specific combination of classes exists.

Lets say the markup looks like this:

```
<span class="target one"></div>
<span class="target two"></div>
<span class="target three"></div>
<span class="target four"></div>
<span class="target five"></div>
```

The target class will be the one thats needs to be targeted. If any combination involving only any of the three first classes - `one` `two` or `three` is present - give body a class.

Exampel (just showing three combination of the target elements to visualize):

```
<span class="target one"></div>
<span class="target one"></div>

<span class="target one"></div>
<span class="target two"></div>

<span class="target three"></div>
<span class="target two"></div>
```

etcetera.

But no class if any of the other elements are present. These are dynamic so i cant use them as variables.

```
<span class="target one"></div>
<span class="target one"></div>
<span class="target four"></div>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I find it a bit hard to figure out what you want

Comment: I have a set of elements in the DOM - 1,2,3,4, and 5. 4 and 5 are dynamic. When the set only exists of 1, or 2, or 3, or a combination of 1,2, and 3 - i want to give body a class. if the set has any other elements then 1,2 or 3, I dont want to give the body class

Comment: You should add what you have tried so far

Comment: I haven´t tried anything that would be relevant. I looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377207/jquery-selector-selecting-a-certain-combination-of-classes-when-multiple-exist but i could only get that to work of the classes was inside the same element  but that would not push my question further IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.

```js
var d = ["one", "two", "three"];
var t = [];
$('span.target').each(function(i) {
  t.push($(this).attr("class").replace("target ", ""));
  if (i == ($('span.target').length - 1)) {
    var l = true;
    for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
      if ($.inArray(t[i], d) == -1)
      {
        l = false;
      }
    }
    if(l){
      $("body").addClass("AddMyClass")
    }
  }
})

console.log("The body has the class AddMyClass: " +$("body").hasClass("AddMyClass"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="target one"></div>
<span class="target two"></div>
<span class="target three"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah that seems like what im looking for - works great